# Interpret the relationship between weights before the output layer and the weights in the first layer

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

[image]

I took a lot time doing research in neural network recently. Last time I asked questions about interpret neural network result from a similar picture and it really activated my interest.

For now, my new question is can we build an equation between `W21` and `W11,W12,Wx21,Wx22` from the plot?

From my perspective, `W21 W22` are the weight for the two neuros in the first hidden layer, and it should have a relationship between something like `W11` and `W21`. Then we can directly know the 'weights' of `X1` and `X2` corresponds to Y. It sounds like the back-propagation, starts with `W21` and ends at the node `W11`.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to find something like $x_1a_1+x_2a_2+b=y$ where you can figure out $a_1,a_2,b$?

Comment: @gunes Hi, not quite true, but similar. I want to know how the `neuralnet` package in R calculate the `W21`,  `W22`? Should there be an relationship with `W11, 12,Wx21,Wx22`?

Comment: There is no direct relationship. Once the feedforward calculation completes, backpop calculates updates for `W21` and `W22` by using *next* layers, not previous.

Comment: So from this plot, we cannot know the obvious relationship between `W21` and `W11` ?

Comment: There is no direct mathematical relationship between these parameters. They're free parameters and are learnt through backprop.